# Accessing Core Data Entity Relationship in NSPredicate with JOIN

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I recently made the switch from direct SQLite (using FMDB) to Core Data, so I'm rewriting a bunch of queries as `NSPredicate`s. I can't figured out how to do a `JOIN` with a predicate.

I have an **Entry** entity and it has a **to-one** relationship with an **Aircraft** entity.

**Entry** has an attribute called `duration` and **Aircraft** has one called `categoryClass`.

I can sum up all the the `duration` values like this (assume that I set up `context` and `request` previously):

```
//SQLite equivalent: SELECT TOTAL(duration) FROM entry    

NSArray *entries = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSNumber *totalDuration = [entries valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
```

But now I want to sum all the `duration` values for certain kinds of **Aircraft**:

```
//SQLite equivalent: SELECT TOTAL(duration) FROM entry LEFT JOIN aircraft ON entry.aircraftRegistration = aircraft.aircraftRegistration WHERE aircraft.categoryClass != 'Simulator' AND aircraft.categoryClass != 'Flight Training Device'"

NSArray *entries = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSNumber *totalDuration = [entries valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration ?????"];
```

I'm guessing this isn't possible with the shorthand `@sum` notation, and I may have to use an `NSPredicate` in my fetch request, but I can't figure out how to do a `LEFT JOIN` on a predicate either:

```
//This results in a crash
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entry.aircraft.categoryClass != 'Simulator'"];
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I pull the full list of entries like I did before:

```
NSArray *entries = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Then on that array, I apply another predicate that uses the conditions on the relationship **Aircraft** entity like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicateWithoutSim = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aircraft.categoryClass != 'Simulator'"];
NSArray *entriesWithoutSim = [entries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateWithoutSim];
```

And then I can sum the durations like I did before, but on the newly-filtered array:

```
totalDuration = [entriesWithoutSim valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
```

Woohoo! :)